# Lenovo Yoga 2 13 is not connecting to second monitor with HDMI to DVI-D

Tags: hdmi, dvi

I own a Samsung SyncMaster P2270 monitor, and I tried to connect it to my Lenovo Yoga 2 13 laptop as a second monitor. The Samsung monitor has a DVI <strike>output</strike> input, and my laptop comes with a micro HDMI port. So I bought an HDMI to DVI-D cable and a micro-HDMI to HDMI cable. I connected the monitor, and then the screen on the second monitor goes to black. It is not saying it is not connected. It just goes black.

When I connect the HDMI to DVI cable to an other laptop, the monitor does work. Or if I connect my laptop with the micro-HDMI-to-HDMI adapter to a TV, it also works.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Just for clairty, can you confirm that the second monitor works with another computer please

Comment: WinKey + P > set to extend. EDIT: You may additionally want to right-click on the desktop > Screen Resolution > hit the the 'Detect' button on the right.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the F10 key (which toggles the display between the computer and an external device)?

Answer (score 0):

I am sometimes (not always) having the same issue on Lenovo Yoga 13. The only workaround I was able to find was to

1. connect the display (image goes black)
2. switch the display off
3. switch the display back on (now the image appears)

I tried several cables, the result was always the same.

It can be good to check your computer with other displays with DVI input to find out more.